# Is there a reason to keep duplicate mastered pins?

Tags: neo-the-world-ends-with-you

In *NEO: TWEWY*, the Garage Sale ability allows you to sell all duplicate pins at once. However, duplicate mastered pins are excluded when selling pins this way. Additionally, the game shows an extra confirmation prompt if you try to sell a mastered pin at a shop.

Considering I can only equip one copy of any pin at once, is there a reason to hold on to duplicate copies of a mastered pin?